# Composer update has removed my changes

Tags: php, git, laravel, composer-php, recovery

I am working on a **Laravel** application, and I ran the command `composer update` in order to install new packages I had added.

I had **changed/added some files in the vendor directory** before that, and those files that were added have been removed. I have *not* committed to my vendor directory (another mistake!), hence I can't get them back through git.

Now my questions are:

1. What happens when `composer update` is ran?
2. Why the files removed are not in the *Recycle Bin*, what has
   happened to them? Permanently deleted?

As well, I am well aware that I can roll back my composer update, but that will not give me back my modified files, it would rather install the original files of the previous version.

Please do let me know if there is any other way (even file recovery) would help me to get these changes back.

Comment: `composer update` will download and replace latest(or other) version of the required packages

Comment: If you use PHPStorm, it keeps its own local history and you can find the lost files it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. `composer update` looks for new versions of installed dependencies and, if found, installs new versions instead of the old ones. It doesn't care whether any changes were made to installed dependencies, because it's looking just at their descriptions stored in the `composer.lock` file.
2. The files most likely cannot be recovered with composer for reasons mentioned above. You can try looking for lost files inside the cache directory `.composer/cache`, but I see no reason whatsoever for the lost files to be there. Yes, they are probably permanently deleted and, if those are critical, you should look for a file recovery program.

You definitely shouldn't store any modifications made to dependencies for the mentioned reasons.

Also, you probably shouldn't add `vendor/` to your repository, for all dependencies are tracked with `composer.lock` anyway, and changing dependencies inside `vendor` (making them hardcoded) is against `composer` workflow.

**EDIT:**

As suggested by Kévin Dunglas, you can also try to look for the lost changes in the local history of your IDE (e.g. [in PHPStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/viewing-local-history-of-a-file-or-folder.html)).

Comment: Normally a good approach to not have to do changes to the `vendor` directory is to use inheritance to override the affected classes and change the bindings in the framework. Especially with Laravel this normally works quite well.

Comment: This actually made me go through the docs for Laravel **again**, in order to realize that you're absolutely right. What a noob mistake though, I have been all over the vendor's functions all this while, and something as such must have happened for me to realize my mistake. Thanks lots for the descriptive answer :) Loads of help that was!

Comment: This actually saved me 16 hours worth of work. Nothing to do with vendor for me actual project files got reverted back to last commit. God save PHPSTORMS local history.

Comment: I using Ubuntu - when i installed new packages it removed all the files inside a vendor folder - as a result, my site went down, How can I recover those files?